# JavaScript merge and join if same ID in one array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

My Data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "ewq123",
    "name": "Joshua",
    "order": "Pizza"
  },
  {
    "id": "ewq123",
    "name": "Joshua",
    "order": "Burger"
  },
  {
    "id": "a512dsa",
    "name": "Eugene",
    "order": "Pizza"
  },
]
```

I want to be able to end up with something like:

```
[
 {
   "id": "ewq123",
   "name": "Joshua",
   "order": ["Burger", "Pizza"]
 },
 {
   "id": "a512dsa",
   "name": "Eugene",
   "order": "Pizza"
 },
]
```

Is there a better way to use ES6 functions? like spread operator

Comment: "Is there a _better_ way to use ES6 functions", better than what exactly? Do you have some code which you're trying to improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below code to acheive the same output :

```
var originalArray = [{
        "id": "ewq123",
        "name": "Joshua",
        "order": "Pizza"
    },
    {
        "id": "ewq123",
        "name": "Joshua",
        "order": "Burger"
    },
    {
        "id": "a512dsa",
        "name": "Eugene",
        "order": "Pizza"
    },
];
var arrayHashmap3 = originalArray.reduce((obj, item) => {

    if (obj[item.id]) {
        obj[item.id].order.push(item.order)
    } else {
        item.order = [item.order]
        obj[item.id] = {
            ...item
        }
    }
    return obj;
}, {});

var mergedArray3 = Object.values(arrayHashmap3);

console.log(mergedArray3);
```

Output :

```
[
 {
   "id": "ewq123",
   "name": "Joshua",
   "order": ["Burger", "Pizza"]
 },
 {
   "id": "a512dsa",
   "name": "Eugene",
   "order": "Pizza"
 },
]
```